# Not receiving response - ajax, codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax | angular controller,

```
$scope.counting=function(id){
  if(id){
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: baseUrl()+'/index.php/site/count',
      data:{"id":id},
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json', 
      success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    },
      error: function() {
       console.log('no response');
    }

  });     

}
```

**Output**
no response

Codeigniter controller,

```
public function count()
{  
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    print_r($input_data); die;
}
```

I am getting the post data, but I am unable to receive any response. 
Problem seems to be at the json_decode part, but it looks fine.

View,

```
<li ng-click="counting(<?php echo $value->id;?>);" class="count"><button type="submit" name="count"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></button></li>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? In the network tab, what is the status of the request?

Comment: Can you give context around what you want to achieve with this? You're posting `id`but it's not being used in your controller?

Comment: @theEUG i will use the 'id' later in the count function. at the moment, on click of the button, i am receiving the button value and the 'id' of the div from which it is being clicked.

Comment: @clu3Less no console error, response is OK. post data shows, response is empty

Comment: remove the die();

Comment: @theEUG 'die' is to terminate the function there. It helps me check if i am receiving the response in the controller.

Comment: Try var_dump($input_data);

Comment: @clu3Less shows null itself. response is coming empty. I have no clue why or how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a more legit solution to the problem.

I removed the button tag in the view,

```
<li ng-click="counting(<?php echo $value->id;?>);" class="count"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></li>
```

Doing so, I do get the response.

I figured, the 'type=submit' was posting the button value directly to the codeigniter controller, and also the 'li' was calling the ajax function, that was also posting the 'id' to the controller.

But, since the 'button type submit' was redirecting to the function count(or to say a new page), the response was unable to show as the response was coming to the previous controller function( or rather i should say previous page). Even removing the 'type=submit' would work in such case.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller send response back to js in  `json` format using `json_sncode()`.Because `print_r()` prints array in `php`, `js` will not recognize it. but you can see array in `network` tab of `console` as response.

```
public function count()
{  
    $id= $this->input->post('id');
    $input_data = array('id'=>$id);
    echo json_encode($input_data);
}
```

Comment: also try with `console.log(data.data);`.

Comment: Same issue again, empty response.
The network tab shows OK:200

Comment: @AtulKumar, In the network tab, copy and paste the Request headers here, including the request data payload.

Comment: That way i receive the Post value .. which i am receiving anyway (print_r($_POST))...
when i click on the button, it is posting 2 values.. the input value and the 'id',
I am receiving the input post value, but not the response which should have the 'id' but is empty